# Windows 10 Start Menu Layout XML - Redirected start menus

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, xml, layout, roaming-profiles

We use redirected start menus and mandatory roaming profiles for specific users and I have been having a nightmare setting up a mandatory start menu. The users are restricted access to the %allusersprofile% and %appdata% links to the local machine. From what I have been reading, I have deduced that you cannot link to ANY other location that is not one of those 2 shares start menu.

It works on other users that have profiles and have access to the allusersprofile perfectly well (well almost) but really could do with some advice.

Heres a snippet:

```
    <start:Group Name="Office" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Word 2016.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Publisher 2016.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Excel 2016.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerPoint 2016.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="2" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Access 2016.lnk" />
    </start:Group>
```

Comment: For anyone else looking, Microsoft have a lovely disclaimer: _Using the layout modification XML to configure Start is not supported with roaming user profiles. For more information, see Deploy Roaming User Profiles._ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/start-layout-xml-desktop

Comment: Found some more information on doing this but gotta test it: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-10/173918-start-menu-roaming-profiles-fix.html

Comment: This is interesting and I also need to test this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/05/08/mysteriously-disappearing-start-menu-tiles-and-roaming-user-profiles/ using _SpecialRoamingOverrideAllowed_ registry entry key

Comment: This is now back on my priority list, along with a tonne of other bugs but I want to get this one out of the way. If I delete a roaming profile, the local user on the machines user folders and clear the entry from profilelist in the registry, the tile data is recreated. This ONLY works the first time a roaming profile logs in. After that, it deletes the local folders and never recreates them. I will post updates especially if I find a full solution.